# Where's the implementation of GenericModel.findAll in Play!framework?

Tags: playframework

I only see this:

```
     /**
     * Find all entities of this type
     */
    public static <T extends JPABase> List<T> findAll() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Please annotate your JPA model with @javax.persistence.Entity annotation.");
    }
```

Where's its implementation ? I mean, i where are those SQL sequences placed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is defined in the JPAEnhancer class which is applied to all JPA Entities:

```
public class JPAEnhancer extends Enhancer {

    public void enhanceThisClass(ApplicationClass applicationClass) throws Exception {
        CtClass ctClass = makeClass(applicationClass);
     ...
        // findAll
        CtMethod findAll = CtMethod.make("public static java.util.List findAll() { return play.db.jpa.JPQL.instance.findAll(\"" + entityName + "\"); }", ctClass);
        ctClass.addMethod(findAll);
    ... 
}
```

Comment: PS: if you need to see the sql generted set the following property to true in yoru application.conf: 
jpa.debugSQL=true